# How to manually determine big number congruences

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How is it possible to determine if the the following congruence is true manually, with resort to a basic calculator?

The real problem here is how to do the math with a such big number?

$$
2015^{50} \equiv 65 \pmod{100}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be $25$.

In mod $100$, we have$$\begin{align}2015^{50}&\equiv 15^{50}\\&\equiv (15^2)^{25}\\&\equiv 25^{25}\\&\equiv 25\end{align}$$
Here, note that we have $$25^n\equiv 25\pmod{100}$$ for every positive integer $n$ because $25^2\equiv 25\pmod{100}$.

Comment: Why is it that $$ 2015^{50} \equiv 15^{50} $$ ?

Comment: And what if mod is other than 100 (eg. 11)?

Comment: @shardl: Because if $2015\equiv 15\pmod{100}$, then $2015^n\equiv 15^n\pmod{100}$ for every positive integer $n$. You may want to look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). If mod $11$, then since we have $2015=183\times 11+2$, we have $2015^{50}\equiv 2^{50}\equiv (2^5)^{10}\equiv 32^{10}\equiv (-1)^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$ (a\cdot 100 + b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk a^k 100^k b^{n-k} $$
Hence, 
$$ (a\cdot 100 + b)^n \cong b^n \pmod {100} $$
for integers $a, b$.

So $2015^{50} \cong 15^{50} \pmod{100}$. Now use $a^{2k} = (a^2)^k$ and the above again, giving 
$$ 15^{50} = 225^{25} \cong 25^{25} \pmod{100} $$
Now $25 = 1 + 2\cdot 12$, giving 
$$ 25^{25} = 25 \cdot 25^{2\cdot 12} = 25 \cdot 625^{12} \cong 25 \cdot 25^{12} \pmod{100} $$
This gives, continuing as before
$$ 25 \cdot 25^{12} = 25 \cdot 625^6 \cong 25 \cdot 25^6 \cong 25\cdot 25^3 \cong 25^2 \cong 25 \pmod{100} $$
Hence,

> $$ 2015^{50} \cong {\color{red}2}5 \pmod{100}$$

Answer (score 0):

You even can check it's with pen and paper:
$$2015\equiv 15\mod100,\quad\text{hence}\quad2015^2\equiv 25,\quad 2015^3\equiv -25\mod100$$
and a trivial induction shows that, for $n\ge 2$,
$$2015^n\equiv\begin{cases}
 -25&\text{if $n$ is odd,}\\
 \phantom{-}25&\text{if $n$ is even.}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary positive integers $m,n;$

$$(10n+5)^{2m+1}\equiv5^{2m+1}+5^{2m}(2m+1)10n\pmod{100}\equiv5^{2m+1}(2n+1)$$

Now $5^r-5^2=5^2(5^{r-2}-1)\equiv0\pmod{100}$ for $r-2\ge0\iff r\ge2$ as $5^{r-2}-1$ is divisible by $5-1$

$\implies5^{2m+1}\equiv25\pmod{100}$ for $2m+1\ge2\iff m\ge1$ as $m$ is an integer